# How do I install Windows 7 without overwriting GRUB?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub)

I have both Windows XP and Ubuntu 10.10 in my PC, now as all know my Windows XP is been attacked by virus, and I need to re-install it by Windows 7 (the reason is not for virus, I need a 64-bit OS).

Now I have to do this, but GRUB shouldn't be crashed by the installation of Windows 7, any ideas?